# Correct way of defining a constructor?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I wanted to know the correct way of defining a constructor in Java. 
This might not be a good question to be asked here but still.

Suppose I have this class:

```
public class Element {
    private String value;
    private Date timestamp;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public Element(String value, Date timestamp) {
        this.value = value;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

Can I define a constructor using the setters?

```
public Element(String value, Date timestamp) {
    setValue(value);
    setTimestamp(timestamp);
}
```

Which is a better design? The first one seems to be the standard and I also have been using it.

Comment: I would rather to use the later, this makes whatever behavior defined on setter method applied to the constructor parameters, and guarantees consistency of member variable.

Comment: There is no correct way, their is what you prefer and what someone else may prefer.

Comment: In addition, there will be some cases where it useful to use the setters to get the same behavior, and others where the setter behavior should differ from the initialization behavior. Again, there is no one correct way.

Comment: The better design is to make your object immutable! Remove setters at all and make the fields final.

Comment: So as per the answer to the du[picate question the second one is not preferred!!

Comment: I could not agree more that there is no correct way as @AndyThomas mention, its depend on the design, case and purpose. Thus it makes the question is more an opinion based question that SO discouraged.

Comment: I'll remove this question as I got some reasonable points for both the designs. THanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we define a constraint in a the setter.

```
public class Person {
   private int weight = 0;

   public Person(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
   }

   public void setWeight(int weight) {
        if(weight > 200) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Weight unreasonable");
        this.weight = weight;
   }
}
```

Now, using the setter, we can introduce a filter, logic or behavior to the class. That a person must not exceed weight of 200. But using the constructor, weight rule are not applied. You can do `new Person(10000)`

So, to save guard the object behavior, its advised that the setter to be used in the constructor when setting member variable's value.

```
public Person(int weight) {
    setWeight(weight);
}
```

Thus, the constructor will not break the intended behavior of `weight`

Comment: actually this is about as **wrong** of advice as you can give in this case because it is relying on side effect that can change with subclasses

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can define a constructor this way. I have done this a few times using swing (JButtons etc.) and it has worked perfectly. It is a neat way to organize the code - especially if you're validating either argument.

Also, it may help with inheritance, where you'd only need to override the setters and use the super class' constructor.

So, at least to me, the second design is better.

Your question is perfectly reasonable!

Comment: this is about as **wrong** advice as you can give because you are relying on side effects that can change with subclasses